# Create Proxy in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, proxy

I have very small old application. It is written on Java 7, and Jetty’s server is used.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
        </dependency>

        ....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The application has several servletes: basically, they are simple - have a couple of
`doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` methods. But one servlet is more complicated - it is a proxy that expands Jetty's ProxyServlet:

```
    public class MyProxyServlet extends ProxyServlet {

        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            // proxy parameters here...
        }

        protected URI rewriteURI(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // proxy requests
            ...
            return new URI(...);
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpClient createHttpClient() throws ServletException {
        }

        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("login");
            this.threadLocal.set(user);
            super.service(request, response);
        }

        public Request addViaHeader(Request proxyRequest) {
            User user = (User)this.threadLocal.get();
            String headerName = PropertiesRepository.instance().getHeader();
            proxyRequest.header(headerName, user.getLogin());
            return super.addViaHeader(proxyRequest);
        }

    }
```

How the proxy works now: it is very simple. First I open on port 8800 address login.html:

```
    url:8800/login.html
```

And then HttpSession object is created, and user login is added:

```
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    int maxInactiveInterval = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesRepository.instance().getMaxInactiveIntervalMinute());
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveInterval);
    session.setAttribute("login", currentUser);
```

Then, the header with user login is created.

Eventually, the proxy accepts the request to the port **8800**, then adds the header, and then forward this request to the port **56833**. That's all.

Now, I need to remake this mini-application on **Java 17** and **Spring But**. I replaced simple servlets with controllers and added the appropriate **@GetMapping** annotations.

Now I have a question: **how can I write simple proxy in a Spring Boot application? Which dependency is needed?**

I can not use Jetty, I need to delete Jetty from the application.

Comment: Maybe, I can use ```spring-cloud-gateway-mvc``` dependency?